# WinRT IDL overload reflection through IMetaDataImport

Tags: windows-runtime, overloading, idl

I'm not sure whether this is new in WinRT or existed before; in IDL, you can write declarations like this:

```
[uuid(E9C62AEE-1494-4A21-BB7E-8589FC751D9D)]
[version(0x06020000)]
[exclusiveto(Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket)]
interface IDatagramSocketStatics : IInspectable
{
 [overload("GetEndpointPairsAsync")] HRESULT GetEndpointPairsAsync(
     [in] Windows.Networking.HostName* remoteHostName, 
     [in] HSTRING remoteServiceName, 
     [out] [retval] Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation
         <Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorView
          <Windows.Networking.EndpointPair*>*>** operation);

 [overload("GetEndpointPairsAsync")] HRESULT GetEndpointPairsWithSortOptionsAsync(
     [in] Windows.Networking.HostName* remoteHostName, 
     [in] HSTRING remoteServiceName, 
     [in] Windows.Networking.HostNameSortOptions sortOptions, 
     [out] [retval] Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation
                    <Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVectorView<
                     <Windows.Networking.EndpointPair*>*>** operation);
}
```

The intention apparently is that the WinRT operation "GetEndpointPairAsync" is overloaded twice, once as GetEndpointPairsAsync, and once as GetEndpointPairsWithSortOptionsAsync.

Is it possible to learn the two underlying operation names through IMetaDataImport? I need to find out in order to generate C code which calls these methods, and all I get from EnumMethods is the overloaded name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overloaded members will have the [`OverloadAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.overloadattribute) custom attribute, which specifies the unique name of the overload.

You can call [`IMetaDataImport::EnumCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231454.aspx) to enumerate the custom attributes of a method definition (MethodDef), identify the `OverloadAttribute` if one is present, and parse its string argument to get the unique name.

Comment: Btw, please note that these artifacts (like the value of the OverloadAttribute) are simply artifacts of the low level IDL authoring experience. They have no representation in the high level authoring experience.